# Rename a PHP JSON Object property while keeping its position

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON object that looks something like this:

```php
$jsonObj = {
  "groups": {
    "first" : {...},
    "second: {
      "Old Name" : {...},
      "others": {...}
    },
    "third": {...}
  }
};
```

I want to change the property name `"Old Name"` to `"New Name"` but keep it as the first property in its parent (`"second"`). Is it possible to achieve it?

*(Of course, I can assign a new property to `"second"` and **unset** the old one, but that will position it at the end of the object, and that's not the result I'm looking for).*

Comment: Is `Old Name` a unique property inside the whole JSON String?

Comment: @christopher, yes it is

Comment: Then is there anything wrong with being crude and using `str_replace()`?

Comment: Objects in JSON are unordered by definition. If you really wanted to retain the order, could you translate `"groups"` to an array instead?

Comment: @christopher, it will work? please submit your solution

Comment: While there might be edge cases where an ordered object *might* be of use, I have to strongly recommend **not** to rely on object member order - any implementation of JSON might change the order for any reason. While not violating the standard, it could break your use case. The [JSON documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) states: `A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.`

Comment: `Old Name` is *not* the first property of `second`. There is no such thing. JSON objects are unordered. You should decode the JSON and sort its contents when you need to use them, or use arrays, which are ordered.

Comment: @Lior [Here is an IDEOne Link](http://ideone.com/E8DBnQ). Although I would strongly look at the recommendations from the other users here.

Comment: @christopher, that's referring the json-object as it is a string?!

Comment: If you wanted to make it show up in the right order, from a php array you could use [array_unshift()](http://www.php.net/array_unshift) to add onto the beginning of the array. But as others have said, the order in json is not guaranteed when on the client side.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, good point, so what is a "safe" yet effective solution?

Comment: make `second` an array and put the objects in that array?

Comment: I guess array_unshift wouldn't work as you can't specify the key. So you would probably have to add the new key and ksort or create a new array and just overwrite the whole `second` key. But as everyone else is saying. A JSON object is an unordered set. Some browsers even reorder the object when they parse the json because it allows for faster lookups and indexing. There is no fix for that except changing from an object `{ }` to an array `[ ]` which will have numeric keys.

Comment: @Lior Told you it was crude!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

position in json is undetermined so it is an unordered collection of properties...

Comment: Arrays in JSON are ordered.

Comment: there are no arrays in the question.

Comment: @sgroves The question references retaining order, which can certainly be done in JSON.

Comment: @Nebojsa, please submit your solution

Comment: @Lior how you mean "submit"?:)

Comment: @NebojsaSusic, the info you added is important however it doesn't answer my question. Can you add w working example of what is the best way of achieving it

Comment: @Lior Actually I have no idea how preserve order in something what is unordered by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The order in an object is not guaranteed. If you want to maintain order, you have to store the objects in an array.

Change the key and store the object in an array at the same time.

Do something like 
...second["new one"=>{...},"others"=>{}].....

Comment: problem is that I have lots of dependencies relaying on this structure. I'd like to keep this structure as it is.

Comment: I would suggest creating a new object with the same structure as the old one and only changing "new name" and equating it to old object. That would keep it the same. But keep in mind that when the script is running, the order is not what you think it is. Objects are not ordered in any specific way.